# CSS active selector (animation)

Tags: css, animation, svg, hover, png

can someone look at this css code please. "hover" function working fine, but "active" not. When I click on the Logo nothing happend. What is wrong in this code?

```css
.splash-logo {
    background: transparent no-repeat;
    position: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 320px;
    background-image: url(logo.svg);
    animation: none; 
}

.splash-logo:hover {
    width: 500px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    background-image: url(logo-hover.png);
    animation: logo_hover 0.5s steps(10) forwards; 
}

.splash-logo:active {
    width: 502px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-image: url(logo-jammin.png);
    animation: logo_jammin 0.7s steps(16) infinite; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
         <div class="splash-logo"></div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Format the code, please. This is a mess

Comment: Active works only on a or button elements.

Comment: @Colin that's not true. It actually works on all elements according to w3 schools. At least on IE8+ and modern browsers.

Comment: @MarkBaijens agree, I did some research and it really works on any element.

Comment: and can we see the html also ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M2Caw5yv and full css https://pastebin.com/DtdSmT7c

Comment: @Seuss Can you create a [mcve] here in the question? Preferablky in the form of a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The url of your background images might be incorrect? If i use background color it seems to work fine.

If the url is not the problem it is probably in your animation effect. But need to see the css code for that to judge.

```css
.splash-logo {
    background: transparent no-repeat;
    position: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 320px;
    background-image: url(logo.svg);
    background-color: yellow;
    animation: none; 
}

.splash-logo:hover {
    width: 500px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    background-image: url(logo-hover.png);
    background-color: green;
    animation: logo_hover 0.5s steps(10) forwards; 
}

.splash-logo:active {
    width: 502px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-image: url(logo-jammin.png);
    background-color: red;
    animation: logo_jammin 0.7s steps(16) infinite; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
         <div class="splash-logo"></div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: The url of background is OK, [js](https://pastebin.com/acjvrbj7),  [css](https://pastebin.com/DtdSmT7c)

Comment: As i said in my post. If it's not the URL then I need the css code of your animation to help further.